# How to run WRF-VPRM

Tags: wrf-chem

Chem Users!

Is there any guide on how to run WRF-Chem with online VPRM calculations for implementing biogenic CO2 emissions? Recently I have run successfully VPRMpreproc using the WRF-VPRMpreproc manual and useful advices from the scientists of Max Planck Institute for Biogeochemistry. Now I am trying to find out how to implement the VPRMpreproc results (e.g. EVI, LSWI, VEG_FRA, etc.) to run the WRF-Chem with online VPRM calculation. I read through WRF-GHG and WRF-Chem User Guide but found only that the WRF_VPRM_input file has to include all VPRMpreproc fields. In addition, I prepared such file and set it as an auxinput15 in the WRF-Chem namelist.input (as well as corresponding chemistry options e.g. chem_opt=16, emiss_inpt_opt=16, emiss_opt=16). The WRF-Chem log tells that the file was read successfully. However there are no any changes in CO2_BIO filed.
Thank you very much indeed